# Is perceived time compressed or expanded while dreaming? (or does it match reality)

Tags: brain, perception, dreaming

I often dream long extended dreams.  Sometimes I wonder if the timeline of the story of my dream occurs compressed, in a moment, or other times extended slowly over a long duration.

- Is there any way to scientifically detect this, and how would it be accomplished?
- Are there any prior examples of this study being performed?

Comment: Cognitive Science SE might be a better community to ask.

Comment: I agree, this isn't really a Biology question, although it's an interesting question.

Comment: OK asked it here: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/10521/8716

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is already cross-posted in cogsci.se which is probably a better site for this question.

Comment: @WYSIWYG agreed, definitely.